# How to save cancellable in database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, playframework-2.0

Currently I try to save a cancellable from an Akka scheduler in my database.
I have an object that has two fields of the type `Cancellable`. (`akka.actor.Cancellable`)

```
private Cancellable warningTimer;

private Cancellable cancelTimer;
```

The problem now is that I can't save them into my database.
One solution would be to save the cancellable after [serialization](http://www.easywayserver.com/java/save-serializable-object-in-java/) in Java and convert it back if I need it.
Another is to use [Hibernate](http://www.hubberspot.com/2013/01/how-to-save-object-in-database-using.html) but for both ways I have to write my own cancellable class, right? (Sorry, I never made something like this before)

```
public class WarningTimer extends Cancellable {...}
```

Now the question is: Is there an easier, more performant way to set / get my cancellable in / from the database and if not which of the both options above is the preferable one?

Comment: Is `Cancellable` from `java.util.concurrent`?

Comment: First, you need to ask "why do I need to do that?" and "Is that really necessary?" `Cancellable` is just a interface, and it represents some scheduled task that can be cancelled. Imagine you save it to database, what does that operation mean? Does that mean the task will be cancelled? What does it mean to load it from the database? Reschedule? What's the point?

Comment: Maybe just mark them as `transient` and populate them later upon user request or some trigger.

Comment: Its from akka.actor.Cancellable. @xiaofeng.li I have multiple objects and each needs its own Timers. Because e.g. the warningTimer needs to send a mail after a time depending on the object, so each object has a different timer. I want to save it in the db because if I just save it in an e.g. ConcurrentHashMap all the timers are lost if the application crashes or a new version is released.

Comment: The point is, `Cancellable` is not supposed to be created by your code, it's returned by the `Scheduler`. Don't try to save it. Save whatever information that's needed to reschedule the task.